# Figure out what is f(1,1) from partial derivatives

Tags: integration, derivatives

So i have a question to figure out what is f(1,1) when
$$\frac{∂f}{∂x}=8x+5y$$
$$\frac{∂f}{∂y}=5x+2y$$
$$f(2,2)=20$$
I tried to integrate both partial derivatives and then i got
$$f(x,y)=4x^2+5xy+C$$
$$f(x,y)=y^2+5xy+D$$
Then i figured out what was C and D by f(2,2)=20 and i got
$$f(x,y)=4x^2+5xy-16$$
$$f(x,y)=y^2+5xy-4$$
But something went wrong because it gives 2 different answers to f(1,1), so
$$f(1,1)=-7$$
$$f(1,1)=2$$
Does anyone know what went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you should get $$f(x,y)=4x^2 + 5xy + C(y)$$

Note, $C$ can be a *function* of $y$, so long as it is constant wrt $x$.

Similarly, $D$ should be a function of $x$.